# Java spring boot: include nested object property in nesting object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In one of my REST(-ish) controller methods i receive a json body like the following:

```
{
  id: 123,
  otherId: 456,
  // ... other properties
}
```

I want to automatically map this to a class with the following structure

```
class Foo {
  int id;
  Bar otherId;
  // ...
}
```

where Bar is

```
class Bar {
  int id;
}
```

So what i want to do is map `otherId` to id within `otherId.id` `(Bar.id)` and simply change my method signature to.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void doThat(@RequestBody @Valid Foo)
```

Are there any Annotations that can do this for me or do i have to write a wrapping method myself, etc? Is this possible the way i hope it is?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the annotation `@JsonDeserialize` to create your own deserializer like this:

```java
class Foo {
  int id;
  @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
  Bar otherId;
  // ...
}

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Bar> {
@Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int id = (Integer) ((IntNode) node.get("id")).numberValue();
        String itemName = node.get("itemName").asText();

        return new Item(id, itemName, new Bar(id));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you change your code to use @JsonDeserialize and extend StdDeserializer for upcoming help-seekers please? Because this is about JSON->Object

Comment: Ok, sorry, no problem.